# DELL XPS13 restarted for update- now freezes after 30 to 90 seconds, even if not logged in

Tags: 14.04, dell, freeze

So I've been using my Dell XPS13 for almost 6 months now, preinstalled from dell with 14.04.  A few initial issues, upgraded kernal to 3.19 and put intel wifi chip in.  It's been working awesome.

Updated this morning, asked to restart, after restart it freezes, totally, no CTRL-ALT f1 or f2 to get to terminals, freezes sometimes on login screen, 30 to 90 seconds.  only way I can get it to restart is ALT Prtsc R E I S U B.

Not sure where to go to start solving problem.

Thanks

Comment: Does it get hot or "misbehaves" in another way it didn't before? What did you "update this morning"?

Comment: no, working great.  IT was fine until the restart after update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running "sudo apt-get autoclean" This will remove any old packages, and show if any additional updates are needed.

Comment: It freezes before I have time.  Usually before I can login

Comment: do you still have the live cd/usb If so run that in "try ubuntu" mode, install updates in th terminal with "sudo apt-get update"  "sudo apt-get upgrade"  "sudo apt-get autoclean " then go to install in live mode and select repair current Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Thanks for the quick responses.  I think I got it fixed.  On dell XPS you have to hit  to get to grub.  Then start advanced options Ubuntu.  turn on networking, then dpkg to update all.  It had some kernal 3.19 updates.  Then reboot, I quickly hit  f1.  sudo apt-get update and upgrade and autoclean.  rebooted and it works!!